# Let's cross on/at the green light. which one is correct?

Tags: prepositions

> Let's cross **on** the green light.
>
> You should cross **at** the red light.

I've heard both expressions used, but not sure which one is right.

I've also seen on the internet that

> You cross *at, on, with* a green light, and the meanings are slightly different

But I don't know the difference of those.

What is the right preposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most idiomatic expressions are:

> Stop at the red light
>
> Proceed when the light turns green, or when the light is green

The next most preferable would be:

> a car proceeds on a green light
>
> you may cross with/on a green light

There is something a bit odd about "cross at the green light". However,

> If you are standing at a green light, there's no reason not to walk across the street